# how to get the id of element inside render and pass it to a function

Tags: reactjs

I have the following in the render section of my reactjs code:

```
<li><a  id="profile" ref="profile"
onClick={() => this.handleClickOnLink("profile")}>Profile</a></li>
```

So far so good. However I do not like having "profile" which is the id of the element hard coded. Instead I want to pass it like this:

```
<li><a  id="profile" ref="profile"
onClick={() => this.handleClickOnLink(this.id)}>Profile</a></li>
```

But it does not work. Any idea how I can do that in a right way?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that arrow functions does not bind it's own `this`. Instead it actually refers to the originating context. Read [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

One possible way to achieve what you need is using the `event.target` object:

```
handleClickOnLink(event) {
    console.info('elem id:', event.target.id);
}
render() {
    return (
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a id="profile" href="#" onClick={this.handleClickOnLink}>
                    Profile
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    );
}
```

The `event` ([`SyntheticEvent`](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html)) object is passed to elements event handlers like the `onClick`. Read more [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html), and also how to provide [extra arguments](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html#passing-arguments-to-event-handlers) to event handlers.

Note that `handleClickOnLink` function needs to be properly binded to the component instance in the class constructor, or change it's definition to an arrow function.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleClickOnLink = this.handleClickOnLink.bind(this);
  }
  handleClickOnLink(e) {
    console.info('elem id ->', e.target.id);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a id="profile" href="#" onClick={this.handleClickOnLink}>
            Profile
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a id="extra" href="#" onClick={this.handleClickOnLink}>
            Extra
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks. what if I need sth like this as well: className={this.state.activeLink ===id of the element? "navigation-active-bold" : ""}. How can I get the id of the element in this case?

Answer (score 2):

You can get the id through the `ref` of the `<a>`. You are using the legacy `ref` so I'll do it with the new way.

```
<li>
  <a
    id="profile"
    ref={(ref) => { this.profile = ref; }}
    onClick={() => this.handleClickOnLink(this.profile && this.profile.getAttribute('id'))}
  >
    Profile
  </a>
</li>
```

Comment: I get the following error:Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of undefined

Comment: @HamedMinaee You sure you're doing exactly what I wrote? You need to check for `this.profile` to exist like I did (`this.profile && ...`)  to prevent that.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code. You can do it without making use of ref and use the event instead

```
handleClickOnLink(e,data){
  console.log(e.target.id,data);
}

<li>
    <a id="tester" onClick={(e) => 
       this.handleClickOnLink(e,"profile")}>
       Profile
    </a>
</li>
```